# MySQL Update if exists, insert if not, delete if not exists (week schedule profile)

Tags: mysql

I've searched quite a while but I did not find an answer for my question. First let me explain where my question comes from.

I have a web-application that has a user-form in which the user can specify on which days of the week he/she is available and what the office times are at this days. Imagine this as a webform with checkboxes for mo-su and from-time, to-time dropdowns for each checkbox/day. Now if a user profile was inserted to the database table I have something like this in my table:

```
idUser | idDay | fromTime | toTime

     1 |     0 |    08:00 |  09:00
```

(in this example 0 stands for Monday (0=mo - 6=su))

Of course there is the feature to change the users profile. So it might be possible that first the user was available mo-fr from 5am to 3pm. Now the profile is changed so that the user is only available mo, fr from 5am to 3pm and we, th only till 1pm AND on sa from 9am-5pm, In this case I have to update the existing entries, to delete the removed entries (tue in this example) and to insert the new available days.

Right now I first delete all entries for the user and the I perform a new insert. This is quite easy and in this case probably the best thing to do (because there are max. 7 entries for each user). BUT the same problem could appear in a different situation where it might be better to optimize the query.

So finally my question is: Is it possible to perform an update if exists, insert if not and delete all other entries in just ONE query?

I hope my question is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing is just to delete all instances then create a new schedule for the updated entries. It sounds like you are trying to do some premature optimisation of the process which IMHO will not be necessary. If you find that deleting all existing entries and replacing them is a performance bottleneck then you might want to consider using an approach which tries to minimise the additional inserts but I think that this would probably end up actually being more work than the simpler option of just removing everything and replacing it

Comment: Hi, I think the same way as you do. But JvdBerg is right if you do not know how many rows will be deleted/inserted. So if the number of possible entries is strictly limited to a few (in this case 7) I tend to use the solution I currently use and that you suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a `INSERT` AND `UPDATE` AND `DELETE` in 1 query.

You have some options:

- In **MySql**: write a stored procedure that handles your problem, and call the stored procedure to perform the task. 1 call from PHP gets the job done.
- In **PHP**: write some code to perform the task and wrap it in a transaction.

If you would ask what's the best method to get the job done, you'd probably start a war. I put my money on the PHP solution.

Comment: Hi, thank your for the quick response! Would you agree with me that in case there are only few entries in the DB it is ok to delete all and insert the new set of entries?

Comment: No I would not. First, you never know how many entries there will be. Second, you should do things as they really are, and not take a shortcut, just because that is convient in programming.

Comment: Hi, but in the example I know there will never be more that 7 entries per user (as the week has 7 days :-)). So maybe in this case the shortcut is ok... Otherwise you are perfectly right!

Comment: I would argue that you want to do the simplest thing you can until there is a requirement to do something else. Removing everything and replacing it is the simplest thing to do until something else like a performance requirement mandates something else